# Can I prevent Google from appending US geolocation to search results for the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-chrome, localization

When I use Google to search for apps to download for my Android (example: https://www.google.com/search?q=javazone+app), all the hits for the Google Play Store send me to pages where I cannot download the app! The button is greyed out. Since I am a developer, I noticed the funky looking query parameter `gl=US`, which is a bit peculiar given that I do not live in the US, but Norway (country code = NO). The `gl` parameter [is what Google uses to geolocate users](https://www.link-assistant.com/news/googles-gl-parameter-explained.html). The weird thing is that the [`hl` parameter (host language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271747/what-does-hl-stand-for) is set to NO, so it seems like Google is trying to give me localized results. You can see the results here:

[image: geolocation us image showing greyed out button]

After deleting the parameters for Norwegian language and US location I get the non-greyed out install button:
[image: non-us image]

Is there a way of preventing Google from doing this? I assume this should pose a problem for others doing the same, but it could be that there is some HTTP Header Chrome is sending that I am unaware of that does this.

The search results are not the same globally, as the `hl` parameter shows, so it's really the `gl` parameter that seems to be off and make the results unusable.

It does not seem to be Chrome specific. When doing searching in Safari on Desktop, the same thing applies. Search results from Google Play often (not always) get the `gl=US` param appended, breaking the install feature. In the below Safari screen you can see the url of the second hit in the bottom of the screen.

[image]

**Related to Google settings?**
When doing the searches in Incognito Mode in Chrome I do not see this issue. Somehow related to the Google session/settings, but how/what?

Changing my browser language settings make no difference, it seems. I am sending this:

```
Accept-Language:
no,nb;q=0.9,nn;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,nb-NO;q=0.5,en-NO;q=0.4,da-NO;q=0.3,da;q=0.2,sv;q=0.1
```

Comment: In my understanding you are getting the `hl=gsw&gl=US` parameter because this is the URL Google has saved to their search index. In my search results the third entry has exactly the same url.

Comment: Maybe you should ask yourself why this app is not available for old versions of Android. And to create app just to show the program of conference is a bit.....

Comment: @RomeoNinov You are misunderstanding what the issue is here. The type of app is irrelevant. This was just an example. This has nothing to do with devices. It is simply that the indexed search result sets the gl code to US, which is not an intended audience, while removing it will use my actual location, thus showing the app as installable.

Comment: @Robert If you are getting `hl=gsw` (and not `hl=no`) you are indeed getting different search results than me. Not sure what language gsw is.

Comment: @oligofren, maybe it is something from Chrome/mobile OS because on desktop, FF, Edge I do not see this effect

Comment: @RomeoNinov I get this on Safari as well. It seems to be related to logged in sessions. Incognito mode will not have any of the query strings present.